# Read line for line of a WinRT TextBox in C#

Tags: c#, windows, textbox, windows-runtime, line

How i can read the content of a Windows 8 WinRT TextBox line for line in C#? I found nowhere a method for this? It's not working like in .Net

Comment: You should probably give this question a little more meat. So that people will know what to answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = textboxName.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

would give you lines from a textbox explicitly split according to the content of the box.  (Removing empty entries accounts for the fact that `Environment.NewLine` is actually two characters long.)

If you want to get a string split by the UI in a multiline textbox (i.e. where wrapping occurs) you'll have to go into more detail with measuring strings, etc, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you *absolutely have to have the strings as laid out by the UI*